# Adding the references to the project just before the build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, project-reference

I need to add some references to another project or dll just before the build process in Visual Studio 2015 starts and then I need to remove the reference after build.

Is it possible and what is the best approach for this?
Can I also add shared projects?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would do this...

Comment: I have a Xamarin.iOS project which has basic functionality and the ability to be extended by the add ons. Add ons are created by client code, so it should not be checked int to the original source control (which is TFS).

Xamarin.iOS cannot add library's dynamically and load them during runtime, so I need to add them statically during the build.

Comment: How about packing those references to a nuget package, install this package by PowerShell script, then add this PS script to the Pre-build event? I`m not PS expert, so I could not give the answer, add a comment just for suggestion.